# Vowel finder, error: list index out of range

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner.
I am trying to make a program which can find vowels in a input string.
Please Help !

```
    #python 3.4.3

    z = ['a','e','i','o','u']

    n = input('Input string')

    a = list(n)

    m = []

    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a)):
             if z[i] == a[j]: # try to match letter by letter
                print('vowel found')
                m.append(z[i])
             else:
                continue
    print(m)
```

And the output:

```
Error:
line 12, in <module>
    if z[i] == a[j]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `range(len(a))` should be `range(len(z))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code can be modified as follow:

```
  for i in z:
    for j in a:
         if i == j: # try to match letter by letter
            print('vowel found')
            m.append(i)
         else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
vowels = 'aeiou'
string = input('Input string > ')
vow_in_str = []

for char in string:
    if char in vowels:
        vow_in_str.append(char)

print(vow_in_str)
```

Note: it's more 'pythonic' to give your variables more expressive names, as well as iterating through the elements in a for loop, rather than the index, whenever possible.

Comment: Also op indicated Python 3.4 , raw_input is not there in Python 3.x , you should use input .

Answer (score 3):

Here's a much faster one:

```
z = ['a','e','i','o','u']

n = input('Input string: ')

m = [x for x in n if x in z]

print(m)
```

No need for that double loop, they take too long once you get into bigger lists.

```
>>> Input string: hello
>>> ['e', 'o']
```

Comment: Good suggestion, however since OP is a complete beginner, list comprehension is probably not the most intuitive thing to grasp. So [here's the resource that taught me list comprehension](http://howchoo.com/g/ngi2zddjzdf/how-to-use-list-comprehension-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

with sets:

st = "Nice day"

```
z = ['a','e','i','o','u']
# convert st to list of chars
y = [ch.lower() for ch in st if ch != ' ']

# convert both list to sets and find the lenght of intersection
print(len(set(z) & set(y)))

3
```